# What is the difference between MOKE hysteresis loop and VSM Hysteresis loop?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, quantum-optics, instrument, electromagnetism

I need to understand what is the difference between Magneto-optical Kerr effect (MOKE) hysteresis loop and vibrating sample magnetometer (VSM) hysteresis loop? And the use of each one of them?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOKE is an optical technique that relies on the rotation of the polarization of light incident on a material with a nonzero magnetization. It is typically used for 2 dimensional materials.

VSM is a bulk thermodynamic probe that is measured by vibrating your sample within a set of coils. You measure the induced current in the coils and can deduce the magnetization of your sample. It only works for bulk samples (single crystals or polycrystal powder).

Both techniques roughly give you the magnetization of your sample, say as a function of temperature or magnetic field.